# Cant select elements on Webpage

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation

I'm having major issue trying to select menu two elements on a dropdown.I've tried xpaths, link texts and css selector but it wont select either the password button or logout button.

Xpaths used for Password button: `"//*[@id='app']/header/div[3]/nav/ul/li/a"`

CSS used for Logout button: `["data-logged-in-log-out-button"]`
XPath used for Logout button: `"//*[@id='app']/header/div[3]/nav/ul/a"`

The error im getting for the select password is:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (989, 233).
>   Other element would receive the click: ...

[image: Html and dropdown]

Comment: Please add the exact xpaths or other locators you used.

Comment: What do you want to select - Log Out? What is the exception that you are getting? Can you please share your code that you tried?

Comment: can you share  this HTML code in text format.

Comment: Ive added the Xpaths and selectors ive tried, im trying to select the password button and also the logout button.  The error im getting for the select password is: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a class="accountSettingsTextBase_1u09j40-o_O-accountSettingsItemText_10y8axf-o_O-accountSettingsWithIconText_1tjzlmt" href="/account/settings">...</a> is not clickable at point (989, 233). Other element would receive the click: <div class="borderStyles_5fsn69-o_O-accountSettingsUserInfo_l6g6b1">...</div>

Comment: I see. Do you have some overlay (some translucent screen kinda) which appears when page loads? Looks like your locator is covered by some other element.

Comment: The background should have the translucent cover but the "automation web" text above it is being recognised somehow so i dont understand how the other two arent being picked up

Comment: Could you please try the below code and let me know if you still get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below XPath along with the explicit wait condition.

**XPath:**

```
//*[contains(text(),'Log out')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url here");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log Out")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")).click();;
    }

}
```

If it still doesn't work, please try -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url here");

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")));
    }

}
```

Comment: No its not picking it up, java.lang.NullPointerException, it doest seem to find the element at all

Comment: Then, mate you need to find out what is covering this element. From the given html code, it's not clear. Looks like `<div class="borderStyles_5fsn69-o_O-accountSettingsUserInfo_l6g6b1">...</div>` is covering it. Can you try inspecting it and see if get any thing?